# Symfony2 - get the return of controller in twig template

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.6

my twig template "*backoffice.html.twig"* is on **Egov/AdminBundle** and extends *baseBO.html.twig*

it contains this block

```
{% block notificationD %}  {% endblock %}
```

and in **Egov/PosteBundle/Controller/CcpAdminController.php** i have this function

```
public function getDemandeEnCourAction()
{
    $repo = $this   ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('EgovCoreBundle:DemandeCCP');

    $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb->select('COUNT(d)');
    $qb->where('d.statut  = :statut');
    $qb->setParameter('statut', 'en cour');
    $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
    return $this->render('@EgovAdmin/Default/backoffice.html.twig', array(
        'count' => (int) $count,
    ));
}
```

So when i do that

```
{% block notificationD %} {{ count }} {% endblock %}
```

i have this exception :

```
Variable "count" does not exist in @EgovAdmin/Default/backoffice.html.twig
```

and if i use **render controller** like this nothing to change :

```
render(controller("EgovPosteBundle:CcpAdmin:getDemandeEnCour"))
```

Comment: This is what twig extensions are for: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Where is your twig render method call inside controller? You are missing it. You insert this vsriable there.

Comment: @Cerad i don"t want to create an Extension Class just i have the function , i want to use it in the twig template

Comment: Why not?  The first one you create might take a bit of effort depending on your Symfony development skills.  After that it becomes trivial and will be one of your most used skills.  And instead of fooling around with embedded controllers and what not, a simple {{ demande_count }} will do the trick whenever you need it.

Comment: Okay , i will try it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The poster indicated that a twig extension was too much work but here is an example anyways:

```
class MyExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
  private $em;
  public function __construct($em) 
  {
    $this->em = $em;
  }
  public function getFunctions()
  {
    return [            
      new \Twig_SimpleFunction('demande_count',[$this, 'getDemandeCount']),
    ];
  }
  public function getDemandeCount()
  {
    $repo = $this->em->getRepository('EgovCoreBundle:DemandeCCP');

    $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb->select('COUNT(d)');
    $qb->where('d.statut  = :statut');
    $qb->setParameter('statut', 'en cour');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
  }
```

Define as a service:

```
services:
  demande_count:
    class: MyExtension
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']
    tags: [{ name: twig.extension }]
```

Then use it in whatever template needs it with:

```
{{ demande_count() }}
```

No fuss. No muss;

Answer (score 0):

first you need to inject the var into your twig template

```
/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test")
 * @Template("target.html.twig")
 */
public function getDemandeEnCourAction()
{
    $repo = $this   ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('EgovCoreBundle:DemandeCCP');

    $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb->select('COUNT(d)');
    $qb->where('d.statut  = :statut');
    $qb->setParameter('statut', 'en cour');
    $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
    return array( 'count' => $count);
}
```

and access var into twig template

```
{% block notificationD %} {{count}} {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Variable "count" does not exist in the twig file

Comment: can you post your template pls

Answer (score 0):

**Your Controller:**

```
// AcmeDemoBundle:YourController:getDemandeEnCour

/**
 * @Route("/test")
 */
public function getDemandeEnCourAction()
{
    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('EgovCoreBundle:DemandeCCP');

    $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb->select('COUNT(d)');
    $qb->where('d.statut = :statut');
    $qb->setParameter('statut', 'en cour');
    $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:YourController:count.html.twig', array(
      'count' => (int) $count,
    ));
}
```

**Your template:**

```
{% block notificationD %} {{count}} {% endblock %}
```

Or you can use [render](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/reference/twig_reference.html#render) twig function if you want to call only specific controller's action and render it's result in any twig template.

**Your Controller**:

```
// AcmeDemoBundle:YourController:getDemandeEnCour

public function getDemandeEnCourAction()
{
    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('EgovCoreBundle:DemandeCCP');

    $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb->select('COUNT(d)');
    $qb->where('d.statut = :statut');
    $qb->setParameter('statut', 'en cour');
    $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:YourController:count.html.twig', array(
      'count' => (int) $count,
    ));
}
```

**AcmeDemoBundle:YourController:count.html.twig template**:

```
{{ count }}
```

**In other templates you can now render controller's action:**

```
{% block notificationD %} {{ render(controller("AcmeDemoBundle:YourController:getDemandeEnCour")) }} {% endblock %}
```

See also [Embedding other Controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/quick_tour/the_view.html#embedding-other-controllers) for more details.